# HTML: How to refresh page/document while clicking tabs in each time in html?

Tags: html, tabs, autofocus

I prepared a html page with tabs. Each tab has input field. Below is the html code.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'One')" id="defaultOpen">One</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Two')">Two</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Three')">Three</button>
</div>

<div id="One" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>One</h3>
  One :
<input type="number" min="0.0"   id="txtOne"  autofocus="autofocus"  />
</div>

<div id="Two" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Two</h3>
 Two :
<input type="number" min="0.0"   id="txtTwo"  autofocus="autofocus"  />
</div>

<div id="Three" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Three</h3>
  Three : 
<input type="number" min="0.0"   id="txtThree"  autofocus="autofocus"  />
</div>

<script>
function openTab(evt, Name) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(Name).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  document.getElementById("txtOne").focus();
document.getElementById("txtTwo").focus();
document.getElementById("txtThree").focus();

}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I click each tab and entered some values in input field in first time. While clicking the second time the each tab, the input field has the entered values.Now I want to clear the input fields or reload/refresh the page while clicking the tabs further times and want to set auto focus the input field. Guide me for my situation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reset the value

```
function reset(Name) {
  document.getElementById("txt"+Name).value = '';
}

function openTab(evt, Name) {
  reset(Name);
  // your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Punitha Subramani  for your valuable guidelines.. Now I got my expected output. Thanks..